# Does kafka ensures that every record is processed exactly once if there are multiple servers accessing single topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I will be having 10 servers which would be accessing single kafka topic. how should i ensure that every server(Consumer) will have distinct records to be processed by the server.
I will be having 10 or more instances of my code running. So every instances will act as a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Kafka Consumer Group protocol, you're guaranteed that no two partitions will be shared amongst the same consumer group.

This means if there are 10+ partitions on this single topic, and each of the 10 server shares the same `group.id` consumer setting, then every server is getting distinct events, though not necessarily *unique events*

If you have less than 10 partitions in the topic, then you have idle servers reading nothing until one of the other servers crashes.

Regarding exactly once, you must disable auto commits, manage offset management yourself, and look at the documentation around transactional producers and look at the documentation around the `isolation.level` consumer setting... Otherwise, you're going to get at least once delivery